# Error while displaying image from admin panel in django

Tags: python, django, recommendation-engine

I was trying to upload image from django admin panel and i made  the following changes.However, I am getting this error when I tried to load the image in wine_list page and review_list.The images are stored in media however, it isnt being displayed:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/media/download_1.jpg
Raised by:  django.views.static.serve
'media\download_1.jpg' could not be found
```

here is a code for wine_list

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}
<h2>Wine list</h2>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
{% if wine_list %}
{% load static %}

<div>
    {% for wine in wine_list %}
     <div><ul>
    <li>
        <h4><a href="{% url 'reviews:wine_detail' wine.id %}">
        {{ wine.name}}</a>
         <br>
        <a><img src="{% static wine.images.url %}" height="200"></a>  
        <br>
        <br>
```

here is code for the image section in review_list:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}
<h2>Latest reviews</h2>
{% load static %}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
{% if latest_review_list %}
<div class="row">
    {% for review in latest_review_list %}
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-4">




        <h4><a href="{% url 'reviews:review_detail' review.id %}">
        {{ review.wine.name }}

        </a></h4>
 <br>
       <a><img src="{% static review.wine.images.url %}" height="200"></a>
```

urls.py for winerama folder

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^reviews/', include('reviews.urls', namespace="reviews")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.simple.urls')),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls', namespace="auth")),

]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)   
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your setting file whether you setup for static image path:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
```

Also check image file permission also. its accessible from anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Specify in: {{ review.wine.images.url }}

```
<a><img src="{{ review.wine.images.url }}" height="200"></a>
```

Comment: i corrected the statement still the image is not being displayed